# Here document and input redirection with -

Tags: here-document

What does the following command do? In particular I don't understand the role of `-` in input redirection.

```
 cat <<-EOF | command $argument
    first option


    second option
    EOF
```

Is it mandatory to have the `-` in the input redirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

```
$ cat <<-EOF
    foo
    bar
    EOF
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

In context to your question regarding - in Here document, I will like to add something in Chris answer above

```
cat - filename <<-EOF
    foo
    bar
    EOF
```

Here if you notice in above code; there are 2 `-`. Both have different purpose 1) `-EOF` which truncates the leading tabs in the delimiter.

2)  `cat - filename` : which basically prints first stdin content (till delimiter is found) + filename content. cat specifically provides this `-` to have control over the order of stdin and file content. In above case changing the command to `cat filename -` will print filename and the stdin content (till delimiter is found)