# What does <<-EOC means?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I'd like to know what the minus (-) and the EOC in the command below means. I know some languages like Perl allows you to chose any combination of character (not bound to EOF) but is that the case here? And the minus is a complete mystery for me. Thanks in advance!

```
ftp -v -n $SERVER  >> $LOG_FILE <<-EOC
            user $USERNAME $PWD
            binary
            cd $DIR1
            mkdir $dir_lock
            get $FILE
            bye
EOC
```

Comment: Related: [Here document and input redirection with -](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85206/here-document-and-input-redirection-with)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a here-document redirection.

```
command <<-word
here-document contents
word
```

The `word` used to delimit the here-document is arbitrary. It's common, but not necessary, to use an upper-case word.

The `-` in `<<-word` has the effect that tabs will be stripped from the beginning of each line in the contents of the here-document.

```
cat <<-SERVICE_ANNOUNCEMENT
    hello
    world
SERVICE_ANNOUNCEMENT
```

If the above here-document was written with literal tabs at the start of each line, it would result in the output

```
hello
world
```

rather than

```
    hello
    world
```

Tabs before the end delimiter are also stripped out with `<<-` (but not without the `-`):

```
cat <<-SERVICE_ANNOUNCEMENT
    hello
    world
    SERVICE_ANNOUNCEMENT
```

(same output)

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

```
   If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are
   stripped  from  input  lines  and  the line containing delimiter.  This
   allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a  natural
   fashion.
```

Comment: Stephen Harris, thank you! I can't believe I didn't look for it in the man page. I  just skimmed through EOF and EOC and missed <<-
Thank you, again!